# Is it possible to allow object values as type?

Tags: typescript

I wonder if it's possible to type a variable that only allows values from another object, for example this works with the key 'GOOD' but is it possible to allow 'good' only ? I'm not a native english so it's hard to find it through the documentation

```
export const testType = {
  GOOD: 'good',
};

interface Test {
  a: keyof typeof testType;
}

const c: Test = {
  a: 'GOOD', // works
  a: 'good' // would like to make it work
};
```

Comment: Are you just curiouse or do you have a problem that you want to solve with it ?

Comment: No it's pure curiosity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using lookup types: [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types)

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```